# discord.py if else and elif

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for some friends of mine, and that bot includes responding for some specific persons. With the first one it was perfect, but when I included others, the bot started to spam all the answers in the chat and I don't know what to do

```
vitor = 404119041318584330
rafael = 315642322463490060

if message.author.id == teste and message.content.lower() == 'morning':
    des1 = 'good morniiiing, how are u baby???'
    des2 = 'Hey darling, I want to be with u all the day'
    des3 = 'I love u'
    des4 = 'Youre the best person in the world'
    url1 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783115078215925781/6fe7b4426b4a3c73e2c70c7cb25cd067.gif'
    url2 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783367148587974656/1518430510_tumblr_p2v8jr3yFT1qkz08qo1_540.gif'
    url3 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783367160704925756/1519434149_000000000000002.gif'
    url4 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783367221170405456/e29b67f7e735a9be2fb891a61488437e.gif'
    url5 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783368175114256434/9e21f42413dc4dc3f3d71ec64cbaf1ea.gif'
    url6 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/718543178109550652/783375880546287616/bd24c4048f80f562bd5ec135291bf5e578e4d43e_hq.gif'
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bom diaaaa :heart::heart::heart:', description = random.choice([des1,des2,des3,des4]), color=0xe91e63)
    embed.set_image(url = random.choice([url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6]))
    embed.set_author(name ='Namorada do Vitor')
    embed.set_footer(text ='I love you <3')
    await message.channel.send(embed = embed)

 elif message.author.id == rafael and message.content.lower() == 'morning':
    await message.channel.send('Sorry, youre too old for me')

else:
    await message.channel.send('Youre not my boyfriend')
```

Comment: From just glancing at your code, I'm imagining the spammed message is "Youre not my boyfriend." It seems obvious why this would be the case. In fact, a discord bot sending an message triggers most message listeners - in other words a discord bot `channel.send` can trigger a discord bot to send again.

Comment: If that's the case you need `if(message.author.bot) return` before your other if statements.

Comment: Thank you very very much